# JS simulation framework for creating discrete and triangular distributions

Tags: javascript, frameworks, open-source, simulation

I need a simulation framework in Javascript, which is open source. 
With the simulation framework can create probability distribution:

1. normal distribution
2. discrete distribution
3. triangular distribution

Using the [jstat Framework](http://www.jstat.org/) I can only create the normal distribution.

Is there any better simulation framework in Javascript?
Or how can I use jstat to create discrete and triangular distribution?

Comment: Just take a look at https://sim4edu.com and the OESjs framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SIM.JS random library](http://simjs.com/random.html). It has normal and triangular distributions, while discrete can be simulated using special algorithms like Alastair Walker's method described in his paper "An efficient method for generating discrete random variables with general distributions" (through it seems to be unavailable for public access).

Comment: Since SIM.JS is no longer maintained, I recommend the OESjs framework available from https://sim4edu.com